# Temporary pinning of sensors to ceiling

Tags: electrical

Goal: optimize placement of [PIR (passive infrared) sensors](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiE2sLcwa3hAhXOslkKHfGLDKYQFjAAegQIABAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.acuitybrands.com%2F-%2Fmedia%2Fproducts%2FSensor_Switch%2F88240%2Fdocument%2FCM-Family_pdf.pdf&usg=AOvVaw30M-hdsUyK5lQ09POIrfAg) in 80 foot hallway.

I would like to experiment with the placement of sensors by temporarily affixing them to the ceiling and test to ensure proper \ maximum coverage.

Question: Is there a clever method to `temporarily` affix sensors to the ceiling?  The plan is to screw them into the ceiling once optimal placement has been identified.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Double-sided carpet tape, or blue tape protecting both surfaces with superglue between. (If the ceiling is popcorn, neither of these will work.)

If you have a popcorn ceiling, I'd experiment with thumbtacks superglued to tape on the sensor. My suspicion is that 3 tacks would hold and not make too much of a mess of the ceiling, but you'll have to do a bit of trial/error.

Answer (score 1):

3m adhesive picture hanger refills. You know those hooks that you pull down on the tab to remove them. You can buy refills from the dollar store. When done just pull the tab. No mess.